# Mandatory condition matching in ´where-in´ clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, where-in

Consider a simple where clause

```
select * from table_abc where col_a in (1,2,3)
```

I know the current conditions

- If 1,2,3 are absent, I will not get any results
- If 1,2,3 are present, I will get all results associated with 1,2,3
- If 1 is present and 2,3 is absent, I will get only results associated with 1.

My question is if we can execute the query for the condition for

- If 1 is present and 2,3 is absent, I should still get all results associated with 1,2,3
- However, if 1,2,3 are absent, I will not get any results

  In other words, can I have a particular value in the where-in clause set as mandatory? How can we change the current query?

EDIT : As pointed out in the comment, I have forgot to add the table structure. It is better that I explain the use case as well.

Table 1 : Admins

```
ID  admin_id
-------------
1      001      
2      002
```

Table 2 : Events

```
ID  event_id
-------------
1      110      
2      220
```

Table 3 : Admins_Events

```
admin_id  event_id
-------------
001        110
001        220
002        220
```

Now, as a part of filtering, let's say I have the query

```
SELECT "admins"."admin_id", "events"."event_id" FROM "admins" 
LEFT JOIN "admins_events" ON "admins_events"."admin_id" = "admins"."admin_id" 
LEFT JOIN "events" ON "events"."event_id" = "admins_events"."event_id" 
WHERE (events.event_id IN (110) AND admins.admin_id IN (001))
```

And currently, I am getting the results as

```
admin_id  event_id
-------------
001        110
```

where as I would want something like

```
admin_id  event_id
-------------
001        110
001        220
```

I have to still show the other events associated with the admin even though I do not pass it in the where-in clause. I was thinking to pass all the event_id's every time and match the mandatory event_id and also match the remaining event_ids in case the mandatory event_id is found.

```
SELECT "admins"."admin_id", "events"."event_id" FROM "admins" 
LEFT JOIN "admins_events" ON "admins_events"."admin_id" = "admins"."admin_id" 
LEFT JOIN "events" ON "events"."event_id" = "admins_events"."event_id" 
WHERE (events.event_id IN (mandatory[110], 220) AND admins.admin_id IN (001))
```

How can I change the query?

Comment: how can you get data when they are absent ?

Comment: Absent from what? The entire table? Only one value will be in `col_a` so two or more of them will always be absent from a row.

Comment: Move the events.event_id condition from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT JOIN result. (As it is now you'll get regular inner join result.)

Comment: @jarlh Could you please elaborate your answer.

Comment: Are you using Postgres or MySQL?  Please only tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another condition with `EXISTS` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT a.admin_id, e.event_id 
FROM Admins a 
LEFT JOIN Admins_Events ae ON ae.admin_id = a.admin_id 
LEFT JOIN Events e ON e.event_id = ae.event_id 
WHERE (e.event_id IN (110, 220) AND a.admin_id IN (001))
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM Admins_Events
  WHERE event_id = 110 AND admin_id = a.admin_id
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7WVWWiHF1extrE1K7mnvyA/1).
Results:

```
| admin_id | event_id |
| -------- | -------- |
| 1        | 110      |
| 1        | 220      |
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like in your example you want all events associated with admins who are associated with event 110. In Mysql I'd do it with the following query, which joins admins to events twice: once to filter for the event you need, and once to get all the other events.

However, in your example, you don't need the admins table in the query at all, since you just need the admin ID, which you can get directly from the admins_events table. I left it in, in case your real "admins" table also had other attributes you wanted (name, location, etc) which are not available in the admins_events join table.

The specific query is:

```
SELECT "admins"."admin_id", "events"."event_id" FROM "admins" 
JOIN "admins_events" ON "admins_events"."admin_id" = "admins"."admin_id" 
JOIN "events" ON "events"."event_id" = "admins_events"."event_id"
JOIN "admins_events" AS "specific_admins_events" ON "specific_admins_events"."admin_id" = "admins"."admin_id" 
JOIN "events" AS "specific_events" ON "specific_events"."event_id" = "specific_admins_events"."event_id"
WHERE (specific_events.event_id IN (110))
```

Comment: Great approach. Thank you. But it duplicates if I add another event_id, for example specific_events.event_id IN (110, 220)

Comment: you can change the first part to "Select distinct" to remove duplicates

Answer (score 0):

First, you only need the `admin_events` table.

Then method uses window functions:

```
SELECT ae.*
FROM (SELECT ae.*,
             SUM(CASE WHEN ae.event_id IN (110) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ae.admin_id) as num_110
      FROM admins_events ae
     ) ae
WHERE ae.admin_id IN ('001') AND -- assume this is a string
      num_110 > 0 AND
      ae.event_id IN (110, 220);
```